# zeitgenössische or gegenwärtige

Tags: word-choice

> A study of **contemporary** approaches to this topic.
>
> Eine Studie über **gegenwärtige/zeitgenössische** Ansätze zu diesem Thema.

Which choice is better for "contemporary" in the above sentence? I intend "contemporary" to mean "in the last century or so".

Comment: What does your preferred dictionary say?

Comment: Actually *zeitgenössiche* translates just to *the same time as*. The meaning will only match, if the reference point is known to be the present. *Goethe in der zeitgenössichen Wahrnehmung* would more likely be assumed to relate to Goethe's contemporaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two is rather small, so you'd better give more details about the context.
As an offhand rule-of-thumb I would tend to use *zeitgenössisch* if the period for which it applies is a bit longer (say 2 or 3 decades), i.e. if the topic is something that changes on that time-scale (style of architecture, filmmaking, other similar cultural things - or general opinions like what is widely regarded as good or bad).
*Gegenwärtig* on the other hand would be my choice if it was something that changes faster, like government or management of a company - something that in English you would rather describe as *current* instead of *contemporary*.

**Edit**
In reaction to Sasan's comment

> I intend "contemporary" to mean "in the last century or so".

For a period that long, *zeitgenössisch* might still fit, but depending on context/topic there might be other expressions that are better suited.
You could perhaps say *moderne* (modern) or *neueste* (newest) if it deals with trends that naturally last about a century.
Or you could name the starting point since when this applies, like

> Seit etwa 120 Jahren
>   Seit dem frühen 20. Jahrhundert
>   Seit mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts
>   Seit Beginn des Victorianischen Zeitalters

Comment: I intend "contemporary" to mean "in the last century or so".